# How to download list of restaurants from this site to an excel sheet?

Tags: database, excel, download

I'd like to compile a list of restaurants from [this site](http://www.eyp.ph/search?catid=19127&loc=Metro%20Manila&loc_id=11488&q=Restaurants) and copy it to an excel file.  Appreciate it a lot if anybody can help me with this.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide the full link. Nobody likes to follow a blind link (bit.ly & Co.). I've done it for you this time. Also, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: What platform? What language? What libraries?

Comment: What is the problem. Getting the data or writing the Excel?

Comment: Wow, this site isn't rent-a-coder, man. At least make an effort first and show us what code you have... And at least have the decency to write in more detail, like what type of restaurants and what area, what format you are trying to get it into, etc. What you're asking above is the same as saying "I want a list of every book on Amazon in Excel, thanks".

Comment: sorry, I'm just a noob and don't know much about programming and databases, I'm just starting to learn about rails and as a project I need to create a database of restaurants in manila that we can search using an application like twitter search...I totally don't know where to start except that I know I need the list of restaurants first..Sorry for the link..I just thought that you'd appreciate a shorter link..got used to using twitter...

Comment: Why do you want to use Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If the list is in a table, you can get amazing results using a "web query" in Excel. That'in thet Data menu. I suggest you explore that.